# Is it possible for Inheritance 2 child class to have reference to the same property?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to design a data model using EF Core.

I have a Party class (superclass) that InformalOranization LegalOrganization and Person inherit from. Only LegalOrganization and Person have TaxNumber. Thus, This 2 classes have TaxNumber class property.

```
public abstract class Party
{
    public Party()
    {
        Names = new List<Name>();
    }

    public int PartyId { get; set; }

    public PartyType PartyType { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

}



public class Person : Party
{
    public Person()
    {

    }

    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    public TaxIdentificationNumber TaxIdentificationNumber { get; set; }

}

public class LegalOrganization : Organization
{
    public LegalOrganization()
    {
    }

    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsProfitable { get; set; }

    public TaxIdentificationNumber TaxIdentificationNumber { get; set; }

}


public class TaxIdentificationNumber
{
    public int TaxIdentificationNumberId { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }

    public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }

    public int PartyId { get; set; }

    public Party Party { get; set; }

}
```

I get this error.

> Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_TaxIdentificationNumbers_Parties_PartyId". The conflict occurred in database "Teknowhow.DataModel080519_01", table "dbo.Parties", column 'PartyId'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You could add another class which is derived from `Party` and that includes the member `TaxIdentificationNumber`. `Person` and `LegalOrganization` are then derived from this additional class.

Comment: Well based on your example it should be in the abstract class anyway since it’s a common property

Comment: @noox I just edit LegalOrganization class. It Inherits from Organization. Not all organizations are taxable. Informal organizations (without registration) are not. Thus, LegalOrganization is Derived from Organization. And InformalOrganization (that) is not important on this Question also inherits from Organization, and is not taxable.

Comment: I assume you also have fields in `Organization`. If not: do you really need it. Otherwise I don't know of a good solution. You could just live with a `TaskIdentifiacationNumber` in `Party` but thus also in `InformalOrganizations`. Or two differently named TaxIdentifactionNumbers in the two derived Classes.

Comment: I just stumbled upon Backing Fields (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field). Maybe you could add a protected field `_taxIdentIficationNumber` in `Party`, define it as backing field and expose the protected field with public properties only in `Person` and `LegalOrganization`. But I have not tried that and it's surely not perfect.

Comment: @noox Maybe I didn't understand when you say expose a protected filed in a child class... I get this error: The property 'LegalOrganization.TaxIdentificationNumber' is of type 'TaxIdentificationNumber' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: @AyodArune please add your `TaxIdentificationNumber` class. The related entity configurations will also help.

Comment: @AyodArune - sorry I did not see that this is only a navigation property (saw it after you added the implementation ot `TaxIdentificationNumber`). And my idea was not useful anyway. Because then you could not use `.Include(p => p.TaxIdentifacationNumber)`when querying the data.

Comment: The code you show doesn't throw that exception. Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface):

```
public interface Taxable
{
    public TaxIdentificationNumber TaxIdentificationNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can make `Person` and `LegalOrganization` inherit from it:

```
public class Person : Party, Taxable
{
    // etc.
}
public class LegalOrganization: Party, Taxable
{
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you added the implementation of the `TaxIdentificationNumber` class it's clear now how it should work and what the problem is. The `TaxIdentificationNumber` in `Person` and `LegalOrganization` should only be a reference navigation property using the `PartyId` in `TaxIdentificationNumber` as foreign key.

When I create the database for this model in EF Core 2.2.4 I do not get an error. But the result is not what you want. The `Party` property in `TaxIdentificationNumber` is of type `Party` but on the other side you have a `Person` and `LegalOrganization` type. So EF does not match them and it creates foreign keys for the `TaxIdentificationNumber` in `Person` and `LegalOrganization` which both end in the `Parties` table:

[image]

I tried to use fluent API:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasOne(p => p.TaxIdentificationNumber)
            .WithOne(t => (Person)t.Party)
            .HasForeignKey<TaxIdentificationNumber>(t => t.PartyId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<LegalOrganization>()
            .HasOne(l => l.TaxIdentificationNumber)
            .WithOne(t => (LegalOrganization)t.Party)
            .HasForeignKey<TaxIdentificationNumber>(t => t.PartyId);
```

But here it seems like the second wins. When I wanted to add data I could only assign a `LegalOrganization` to the `Party` property in `TaxIdentificationNumber` (not a `Person`). And for the `Person` a `TexIdentifactionNumberId` was created in the Parties-Table.

When I'm even more specific

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasOne(p => p.TaxIdentificationNumber)
            .WithOne(t => (Person)t.Party)
            .HasForeignKey<TaxIdentificationNumber>(t => t.PartyId)
            .HasPrincipalKey<Party>(t => t.PartyId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<LegalOrganization>()
            .HasOne(l => l.TaxIdentificationNumber)
            .WithOne(t => (LegalOrganization)t.Party)
            .HasForeignKey<TaxIdentificationNumber>(t => t.PartyId)
            .HasPrincipalKey<Party>(p => p.PartyId);
```

I get this error:

> You are configuring a relationship between 'TaxIdentificationNumber' and 'Person' but have specified a foreign key targeting 'Party'. The foreign key must be targeting a type that is part of the relationship.

So I assume EF does not allow such a model. I think it's not easy to create a model which does behave like you want and is quite reasonable. Your model has the flaw that you could assign an `InformalOrganization` to the `Party` property of the `TaxIdentificationNumber`.

The easiest workaround would be to add the reference navigation property `TaxIdentificationNumber` from `Person` and `LegalOrganization` to the `Party` class. With this approach it's even easier to wrongly assign a `TaxIdentifactionNumber` to a `InformalOrganization`. You could add a database CHECK CONSTRAINT with the Discriminator column to prevent this on the database level.

Another one would be to work with two foreign keys. One for `Person` and one for `LegalOrganization`. But this seems to be even uglier.

Comment: Yes @noox. I'm still working on this problem. I don't have a solution for now and no one brings the solution until now. I'm working with TaxIdentifactionNumber in Party for now, while I seek for solutions.